# How to define multiple navigation zones with Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am just learning to build a template in Orchard CMS 1.7.1  And I am using this blog to help me along (http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/05/real-world-orchard-cms-part-2-creating.html).  What I want to do is define 2 zones for 2 different navigations.

I have attemped:

```
var displayMainNav = (Model.Navigation != null);
var displaySubNav = (Model.Navigation != null);

@if (displayMainNav)
{
    <div id="layout-navigation" class="zone">
        @Display(Model.Navigation)
    </div>
}
@if (displaySubNav)
{
    <div id="layout-sub-navigation" class="zone">
        @Display(Model.Navigation)
    </div>
}
```

And I get the same navigation in 2 places

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just have Navigation1 and Navigation2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to define two different named zones, Navigation1 and Navigation2 and then go to your themes theme.txt file and add your two new zones to the list of defined zones so that they will appear in your widgets section where you can add your menu widgets.

Comment: Thanks,  It's that easy!  Not a fan of the Orchard CMS Documentation, but the framework has a lot of potential

Comment: Yeah, docs leave a little bit to be desired, but they are steadily getting better :)

Comment: Especially if people who have constructive criticism go and update it themselves ;) The documentation is open-source, like the rest, so it's only as good as contributors make it.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  Well I'll have to contribute what I can.  Thanks for the info.